# Flash Textfield embedFonts false positive

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, embedded-fonts

I'm working on font embedding in Flash (flas are compiled using CS5 made previously in CS3).

The project is split into a number of separate flas, and I'm having trouble with one particular one.

I'm dynamically embedding the fonts using a class I wrote that sit's on top of the stage listening for Event.ADDED then searching for textfields that have dynamic text and embedding the font needed dynamically (No efficiency requirements here :).

I have a check so that I don't bother processing textfields that are already embedded. No textfields in any of the flas (to my knowledge) have fonts embedded. But some textfields are saying that they are, as in textfield.embedFonts == true.

In the fla global font embedding, that no fonts are embedded. If I click on the actual textfields embed button, I see that the font of the textfield is in the font list, but no character ranges are embedded.

This is leaving me confused, as I want absolutely no fonts embedded in any flas. But the font for the individual textfield is always in the font embed list, no matter how many times I remove it. If i click on the embed button for the textfield to check it there is no embedding then the font is added to the list without any character ranges.

Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

Comment: What does a size report say?  Do you see a font that looks like it is embedded?

Comment: Size of generated swf is 3kb so no actual font is embedded. I'm looking into the xlf package now. Seeing what the XML can tell me.

Comment: It seems that if the textfield was previously embedded it never forgets that it was. You can remove all the char ranges but it will still report that it has a font embedded.

Comment: If I embed a font in a textfield, add some char ranges, textfield.embedFonts == true which is expected. If the font is then removed from the font list and the char rages reset, textfield.embedFonts still equals true. I would expect this to be false. Only way I get get textfield.embedFonts to reset to false is by changing font to system font (_sans) and then back to desired font.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the embedding of the textField so that it uses the system font. That should prevent any font embedding.

Comment: Well I do want font embedding, just not through the flash compiler. But I'll try it as an experiment.

Comment: Well if you set it to system font (each Textfield separately) the compiler won't embed any fonts but you can still embed it via AS just like you intend.

Comment: Yep that is a possibilty, but I feel like I'm avoiding a problem here. I would like to know why the textfields think they have a font embedded. Switching to the system font and then back to the desired font, seems to remind it that it has no font embedded.